# python: replace list items with index of items in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing

I have 2 lists, for example say

```
list1 = ['abc', 'xyz', 'cat', 'xyz', 'abc', 'pqr', 'dog']
list2 = ['xyz', 'dog', 'pqr', 'abc', 'cat']
```

I want to create a new list by replacing `list1` with indexes of the elements in `list2` like

```
list3 = [3, 0, 4, 0, 3, 2, 1]
```

I should mention here that I actually get `list2` from `list1` by

```
list2 = list(set(list1))
```

So `list2` has no duplicates and has all the elements of `list1`.

I want to know the fastest way I can get `list3` in a pythonic way.
I have tried the 2 ways so far:

1> basic `.index` way

```
list3 = [list2.index(item) for item in list1]
```

2> using a dict with elements as keys and indexes as values

```
d = {list2[i]:i for i in range(len(list2))}
list3 = [d[item] for item in list1]
```

Comment: You should include both of your attempts so we aren't giving you duplicate answers.

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity?

Comment: Okay I am adding my attempts @user3483203

Comment: I believe the only approach better than `[list2.index(i) for i in list1]` is to do a "dynamic programming"-like approach by storing indexes of already looked-up values in a hashtable

Comment: »Better way« in terms of ...? More pythonic? Faster? (`[list2.index(i) for i in list1]` is already quite »pythonic« I guess)

Comment: Yes perhaps I should have just mentioned "faster". That's the main goal

Comment: I'd go the dictionary route.  You can build your lookup dict like this `d = {x: i for i, x in enumerate(list2)}` instead.

Comment: Note the order of elements in `list2` are random due to `set()` (sets are undordered).  Thus the indices in `list3` are not reliable and can change between sessions.  This raises the question, what is your ultimate goal?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a concerned about looking up duplicate values, just create an index first:

```
>>> idx={e:list2.index(e) for e in list2}
```

Alternatively:

```
>>> idx={e:n for n,e in enumerate(list2)}
```

Then:

```
>>> [idx[e] for e in list1]
[3, 0, 4, 0, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Why not go directly with the second option? The first is barely faster than doing the `index` lookup directly in the list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

```
idx = dict(zip(list2, range(len(list2))))
list(map(idx.get, list1))
# [3, 0, 4, 0, 3, 2, 1]
```